# Primefaces redirect to login null pointer exception

Tags: jsf, redirect, primefaces, session-timeout

We have a web application that was recently upgraded from primefaces 5.0.10 to 6.0.  We are now having a problem after session timeouts.  When we try to redirect to the login page, we are getting a null pointer exception at line 66 of org.primefaces.util.ResourceUtils.  The problem is that getViewRoot() is returning null.  This is not surprising since the session expired.

```
public static ArrayList<ResourceInfo> getComponentResources(FacesContext context) {
    ArrayList<ResourceInfo> resourceInfos = new ArrayList<ResourceInfo>();

    List<UIComponent> resources = context.getViewRoot().getComponentResources(context, "head");
```

The way this was implemented and that worked in 5.0.10 is that we have a PhaseListener with an afterPhase method that figures out that the session expired and redirects:

```
NavigationHandler nh = facesContext.getApplication().getNavigationHandler();
nh.handleNavigation(facesContext, null, redirect);
```

What is the correct/best way to do this in 6.0?

Apache root cause: 
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.primefaces.util.ResourceUtils.getComponentResources(ResourceUtils.java:66)
    at org.primefaces.context.PrimePartialResponseWriter.startMetadataIfNecessary(PrimePartialResponseWriter.java:280)
 [wrapped] javax.faces.event.AbortProcessingException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.primefaces.context.PrimePartialResponseWriter.startMetadataIfNecessary(PrimePartialResponseWriter.java:303)
    at org.primefaces.context.PrimePartialResponseWriter.redirect(PrimePartialResponseWriter.java:156)
    at org.apache.myfaces.context.servlet.ServletExternalContextImpl.redirect(ServletExternalContextImpl.java:493)
    at javax.faces.context.ExternalContextWrapper.redirect(ExternalContextWrapper.java:386)
    at org.apache.myfaces.application.NavigationHandlerImpl.handleNavigation(NavigationHandlerImpl.java:235)
    at org.apache.myfaces.application.NavigationHandlerImpl.handleNavigation(NavigationHandlerImpl.java:122)
    at org.primefaces.application.DialogNavigationHandler.handleNavigation(DialogNavigationHandler.java:100)

Comment: Please check the PF issuelist, 'fixed' sort of in a later elite release and in trunk. And iirc, there is q/a about this on Stackoverflow to